# A command to list buffers and prepare command line for next instruction

Tags: vim

I want to reduce the amount of effort to list the buffers, select a buffer and either remove it or show it.

At present I need to do the following `:ls` > `[Select the desired buffer]` > `:<Command>`

I want to create this command and then map it `,b` so I only need to press `,b` and have the command line ready for me to use `<buffer number>bw` or `<buffer number>b` of which the number I can select from the already presented list.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve really? I do not understand well the requirements behind that

Comment: Your right I should have taken a step back and asked what was the overall requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mapping should meet your requirements.

```
nnoremap ,b :ls<cr>:
```